# How to update an existing Python Flask web page based on form input?

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

I am trying to build a prediction web application with Flask. The app should take in user input, process it through a python trained model, then display the results as a chart beside the input form.

My code looks like this:

**HTML Form:**

```
<form class = "prediction-options" method = "post" action = "/prediction/results">
  <!--the input fields-->
</form>
```

**Flask app.py**

```
@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')    

@app.route("/prediction/results", methods = ['POST'])
def predict():
    input_aqi = float(request.form['aqi'])/272
    input_pm2_5 = float(request.form['pm2_5'])/224
    input_pm10 = float(request.form['pm10'])/283
    input_so2 = float(request.form['so2'])/36
    input_no2 = float(request.form['no2'])/110
    input_co = float(request.form['co'])/1.83
    input_o3 = float(request.form['o3'])/124
    input_list = [[input_aqi,input_pm2_5,input_pm10,input_so2,input_no2,input_co,input_o3]]


    output_acute_bronchitis = model_acute_bronchitis.predict(input_list)
    output_asthma = model_asthma.predict(input_list)
    output_asthmatic_bronchitis = model_asthmatic_bronchitis.predict(input_list)
    output_aurti = model_aurti.predict(input_list)
    output_bronchitis = model_bronchitis.predict(input_list)
    output_pneumonia = model_pneumonia.predict(input_list)

    d = collections.OrderedDict()
    d['acute_bronchitis'] = output_acute_bronchitis[0]
    d['asthma'] = output_asthma[0]
    d['asthmatic_bronchitis'] = output_asthmatic_bronchitis[0]
    d['aurti'] = output_aurti[0]
    d['bronchitis'] = output_bronchitis[0]
    d['pneumonia'] = output_pneumonia[0]

    prediction = jsonify(d)
    return prediction
```

Right now, I have managed to take in the user input and render the predicted results on the '/prediction/results' page. How can I get the results to show up on the '/' page? I tried to do this:

```
@app.route("/", methods = ['POST','GET'])
def main():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        def predict():
           #predict function that returns prediction
    return render_template('index.html')
```

But I always get a `socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe` error message. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `session` for this, before the last line in your `predict` route, store the prediction with

```
session['prediction'] = prediction
```

and then you can access in any other route in your application, for example you can have this for `/`

```
@app.route("/", methods = ['POST','GET'])
def main():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass

    prediction = session['prediction']

    return render_template('index.html', prediction=prediction)
```